# Add 'active' class to a plain text anchor menu in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to add an active class to an anchor row within a single Wordpress page on a plain text unordered list (i.e. NOT a wordpress menu). I am currently using plugins to add scripts to the header but I can't get anything to work so I'm wondering if I'm making a mistake or if the plugins aren't working.

I've tried every single script I could find on Stack adding a class and nothing is changing. I can't tell if it's the plugins or my code

```
HTML:
<div class="dotnavcon">  
<nav class="ot-anchordots">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#early-years" class="dot"><span>EYP</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#middle-years" class="dot"><span>PYP</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#middle-years" class="dot"><span>MYP</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#diploma" class="dot"><span>DP</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
</div>

CSS: 
.ot-anchordots ul li a.active{color:#FFf; text-align:right; background:#fff;}

JS:
var $navLIs = $('nav.ot-anchordots ul li a')
$navLIs.find('a').click(function() {
  $navLIs.removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});

OR (among others):

const navsStr = '.ot-anchordots ul li a';

$(navsStr).on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  let items = $(navsStr).find('a[href$="' + href + '"]');
  $(items).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');  
});
```

When you click the dot and it goes to the anchor, the link should gain an "active" class: dot should fill in and the name of the row should stay visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue in both cases is that you have the `a` selected and then you run `.find('a')` so therefore you don't have an element selected. This is why it is always good to run an `alert` or `console.log` to check if a variable is blank.

So the first example should look like this (Will add `active` class to anchor that is clicked):

```js
$(function() {
  var $navLIs = $('nav.ot-anchordots ul li a')
  $navLIs.click(function() {
    $navLIs.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.ot-anchordots ul li a.active {
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dotnavcon">
  <nav class="ot-anchordots">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#early-years" class="dot"><span>EYP</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#middle-years" class="dot"><span>PYP</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#middle-years" class="dot"><span>MYP</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#diploma" class="dot"><span>DP</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

The second one should look like this (Will add `active` class to all anchors with same href when clicked):

```js
$(function() {
  var navsStr = '.ot-anchordots ul li a';

  $(navsStr).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var items = $(navsStr).filter('[href$="' + href + '"]');
    var itemsInactive = $(navsStr).filter(':not([href$="' + href + '"])');

    $(items).addClass('active');
    $(itemsInactive).removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.ot-anchordots ul li a.active {
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dotnavcon">
  <nav class="ot-anchordots">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#early-years" class="dot"><span>EYP</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#middle-years" class="dot"><span>PYP</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#middle-years" class="dot"><span>MYP</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#diploma" class="dot"><span>DP</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice! Glad I could help!